# How to ignore errors in redshift copy command

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I've parquet files and need to load into redshift using copy command. The command is getting failed due to spectrum scan error. So I want to ignore the file if any causing error.

Is there any way to ignore records/maxerror option in redshift copy command for parquet file load?

```
COPY <targettablename> from '<s3 path>' iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::1232432' format as parquet maxerror 250
```

Error:- MAXERROR argument is not supported for PARQUET based COPY

Comment: You would be better off looking at [STL_LOAD_ERRORS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_STL_LOAD_ERRORS.html) to see what file is causing the problems, then either remove it from the load or transform it so that it can be loaded.

Comment: Is there any way to remove/ignore the causing error files in copy command?

Comment: Use a manifest.

Answer (score -1):

1. For copying data from parquet file to Redshift, you just use this below format-

Copy SchemaName.TableName
From 'S3://buckets/file path'
access_key_id 'Access key id details' secret_access_key 'Secret access key details'
Format as parquet
STATUPDATE off

2. Spectrum scan error you get when there is discrepancy in source columns data type and destination column data types, for that you have to change data types according to Redshift's standard data type format.
3. For checking errors you can refer this query-

Select * from SVL_S3LOG where query = 'Query_id needs to be placed here'